Stack Overflow Error (0xC0000409) in Python Drawing App with Pressure Sensitive Stylus
I'm developing a drawing app in Python, and everything works smoothly with mouse input. However, when I use a pressure-sensitive stylus, the application crashes after a short period with the following error:
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
I understand this error is due to a stack overflow, but I've double-checked my code and can't identify where the memory leak might be occurring. I've narrowed the issue down to a few event functions that handle mouse and stylus input.
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.mousedown = True
        x, y = event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()
        if y >= self.height() - 80:
            for rect, colour in self.palette_rects:
                if rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                    self.selected_colour = colour
                    print(f"Selected colour: {self.selected_colour}")
                    break
        else:
            self.shade = self.selected_colour
    elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
        self.mousedown = True
        self.shade = self.backdrop

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.mousedown:
        spot = (event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())
        adjusted_radius = int(self.radius * self.pen_pressure)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.transparent_surface, self.shade, spot, adjusted_radius)
        self.update()
        print(f"Spot: {spot}, Radius: {adjusted_radius}")

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton or event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
        self.mousedown = False


def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    print(f"Key pressed: {event.key()}")
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Q:
        self.close()

The main loop is as follows:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not check_license():
        sys.exit()  # Exit the app if the license is not valid

    window = SketchWidget()
    window.resize(800, 800)
    window.show()

    try:
        while True:
            window.update()
            window.clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS
            if not app.exec_():
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        pygame.quit()  # Clean up Pygame before exiting
        sys.exit()

I'm particularly focusing on the mouseMoveEvent function, as it involves pressure sensitivity, which may be affecting memory over time. Any advice on preventing this stack overflow with stylus input or on possible memory issues in the code?

I don't know if it's the cause of your 0xC0000409 exit code, but your main loop seems suspect. I don't think you should be calling app.exec_ more than once (i.e. not in a loop) as that runs the synchronous / blocking mainloop of your Qt application. Since you have multiple "mainloop"s (Qt, widget windows, pygame) you should probably run your separate mainloops in separate threads. Though, as Rabbid76 points out in the duplicate thread, you're better off not trying to mix frameworks.

Thank you Paul. I am removing the pygame stuff now. It's easier said than done but hopefully this will get rid of the issue of multiple app.exec calls.

@Kazber The "easier said than done" is unfortunately a common "beginner mistake". In fact, there should ever be only one event loop (at least for each thread and, therefore each process thread). Calling an "app.exec" multiple times is like trying to call multiple while loops at once: you can't do that within a single thread, and it wouldn't make any sense in trying to anyway. The basic rule of UI is that there should never be more than a "main" thread with its loop, unless you really know what you're doing. The second rule is that, if you know that first rule, you won't try to override it.
